# Why is the same model with nn sequential giving worse results

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to learn pytorch and I am starting with Fashion Mnist dataset. I created a model and it was giving horrible results. I found out that if I rewrite the model without using nn.Sequential, it actually works. I have no idea where is actual difference between these two and why is the one with nn.Sequential not working properly.

This version achieves around 10%

```
class Down(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.down = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size= 3, padding = 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.down(x)

class MyNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            Down(1, 128),
            Down(128,256))
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.net(x)
        # print(x.size())
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        x = nn.Linear(12544, 10)(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim = 1)
```

And this model achieves around 90%

```
class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,128, kernel_size = 3,  padding = 1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1)
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(12544, 10)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(64, 10) 
        self.norm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
        self.norm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.norm1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.norm2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim = 1)
        x = self.lin1(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim = 1)
```

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a linear layer every time you pass an input to your network.

Declaring `nn.Linear` at `__init__` will fix your problem